# How to perform Hibernate Reverse Engineering in Eclipse IDE version 2020-09

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, hibernate-tools

I was trying to use reverse engineering in hibernate in the latest Eclipse IDE but all the resources I came across seem to be outdated.
would appreciate it if I get some input as to how to go about this procedure.

I tried the steps in this link (https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/java-hibernate-reverse-engineering-tutorial-with-eclipse-and-mysql )but was not able to generate the Entity classes with the annotations. This method generated a POJO with no annotations at all.
Would be thankful if I find a way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tick this check box in order to generate EJB3 annotations

[image]